# Swagger UI customize response body

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a question regarding to customize response body in swaggerUI.
Let's say I have an endpoint:
[endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg5T6.png)

where example value for 'localDate' looks like:

```
{
"localDate": "Wednesday, 13 March 2024"
}
```

But when I try it out in response I can find whole object in response:

```
{
  "localDate": {
    "calendar": {
      "id": "ISO",
      "name": "ISO",
      "minYear": -9998,
      "maxYear": 9999,
      "eras": [
        {
          "name": "BCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "CE"
        }
      ]
    },
    "year": 2024,
    "month": 3,
    "day": 14,
    "dayOfWeek": 4,
    "yearOfEra": 2024,
    "era": {
      "name": "CE"
    },
    "dayOfYear": 74
  }
}
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("any-simple-random-object")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<actionresult<anysimpleobjectresponse>> GetAnySimpleObject()
=> await Task.FromResult(AnySimpleObjectResponse.CreateRandomObject());
```

My response generator:

```
public record AnySimpleObjectResponse(LocalDate LocalDate)
{
public static AnySimpleObjectResponse CreateRandomObject()
=> new(LocalDate.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
}
```

The question is, what should I do to have response displayed only in swagger UI like in example (e.g. for postman I want to see whole object).

I'm looking for general mechanism, I don't want to add any attributes for every potential response object or for all endpoints.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or other artefacts. Just copy paste the actual path. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: i don't think any generic solution is possible, you would need somekind of json converter to format the datetime as per your need.